# How to display strings in a WPF ListView in different colours?

Tags: wpf, listview, converters

I would like to fill a WPF ListView with strings using a databinding. My code looks like this (and work! ;) ):

**Xaml:**

```
<ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
</ListView>
```

I left out some code for a better overview.
Entries is an `IList<string>`.

So far, everything is working fine. Now comes the problem: A string in Entries may contain a particular keyword that indicates that this string wants to be displayed with red background inside the ListView. Say we have a method GetBackground(string s) which returns a Colour depending on the string.

How can I make the ListView display its items in the correct colour. 
My first idea was to have a converter converting my string to a colour using the abovementioned method. Where would I have to add this converter and how do I pass the string to the converter as parameter? my first Idea was:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Entries, Converter={StaticResource entryToColourConverter}, 
ConverterParameter=???}"
</ListView>
```

Does anyone have an idea how this could be done? Am I on the right track?

Best wishes,
Christian

**EDIT 1:**
Changed the code (as a first step) towards:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="entryTemplate">
            <TextBlock 
                Text="{Binding}"
                Background="Green"/>
        </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

...

<ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource entryTemplate}>
</ListView>
```

However, this does not work at all. Even if I change the text to some static value, the result is still the same as with the previous code.

**EDIT 2:**
I found the problem, my code looked like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvEntries"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EntriesTemplate}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Entries, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">

            <ListView.View>

                <GridView x:Name="gvEntries">
                    <GridViewColumn
                        HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource hcs}"
                        Header="Entry"
                        TextBlock.TextAlignment="Left">
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>
```

And this ListView.View was the problem. On removing that, everything was working! :) Now I have to find out how to solve this without the ListView.View

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:EntryToBackgroundConverter x:Key="EntryToBackgroundConverter"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EntryTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" Background="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource EntryToBackgroundConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>        
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>              
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EntryTemplate}"></ListView>        
</Grid>
```

Converter:

```
public class EntryToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string stringValue = value as string;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
            return Brushes.Black;

        if (stringValue == "foreach")
            return Brushes.Blue;
        if (stringValue == "if")
            return Brushes.Blue;

        return Brushes.Black;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

You're on the right lines... something like this should work...

Comment: This seems to be just what I need, however, somehow the ItemTemplate is not used. see my edited post.

Comment: @Christian sorry... you need to use . in the binding... i've edited my answer :)

Comment: Hmm I changed it to "." but the problem does not seem to be the datatemplate itself. The datatemplate is not used for some reason. Even if I enter <TextBlock Text="abc" Background="Green"/> it still shows the correct strings. It seems as if the datatemplate is not used. :/ any ideas?

Comment: @DavidMasters84 - This is how my converter also looks like, but the problem is not in the converter, the problem is that even for the smallest example like above, the DataTemplate is not used at all!

Comment: @Christian - I don't know why it's not working because I've tested my example and it works :) A typo somewhere?

Comment: @DavidMasters84 - Sorry about the trouble, see my edit. That's why it wasn't working. I'll try to figure out why this is. Thanks for your great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Create item template for ListView and then tie text color of (for example) label to Entrie property

Comment: Somehow the ItemTemplate seems to not being used. I edited my post and added the ItemTemplate

Comment: well I think this code should work, but I really don't see why the ItemTemplate is not being used. I will now reduce my code to the minimum and see if that works.